# Simple Linux upgrade script in Bash revision 2

Tags: bash, linux, installer

As I will be deploying this script on multiple machines with the very same system Linux Mint 18 with rather same configuration, I would like to be semi-sure I won't screw things up much.

This little script will run every day from the `root`'s `crontab` and will be logged into `syslog` or my own log AFTER this manual script passes some quality checks. Logging is not the question now. Automation is also not the question yet. In the meantime it is being executed as normal user and elevated with `sudo` internally. No help message needed. And no docs needed either. I ran it through [Shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/). I have also ruled out the use of subjectively nicer `apt`, because [it is not meant to be used in scripts.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323015/apt-vs-apt-get-error-code/323025#323025)

Conditions still are:

1. Code readability
2. Output readability
3. Colored headings
4. Attempt to correct things
5. Clean-up after update

My current idea is a little more advanced than the first one, having implemented exit code checking was a great idea:

```
#!/bin/bash


RED="\033[1;31m"
GREEN="\033[1;32m"
YELLOW="\033[1;33m"
NOCOLOR="\033[0m"


function show_success {

  echo -e "${GREEN}Success.${NOCOLOR}\n"

}


function show_error_and_exit {

  echo -e "${RED}An error occured.${NOCOLOR}\n"

  exit "$1"

}

function error_handler {

  if [[ $1 -ne 0 ]];
  then

    show_error_and_exit "$2"

  else

    show_success

  fi

}


echo -e "\n${GREEN}Step 1: configure packages${NOCOLOR}"
echo -e "${YELLOW}dpkg --configure -a${NOCOLOR}"

sudo dpkg --configure -a

error_handler $?  1


echo -e "${GREEN}Step 2: fix broken dependencies${NOCOLOR}"
echo -e "${YELLOW}apt-get install --fix-broken${NOCOLOR}"

sudo apt-get install --fix-broken

error_handler $?  2


echo -e "${GREEN}Step 3: update cache${NOCOLOR}"
echo -e "${YELLOW}apt-get update${NOCOLOR}"

sudo apt-get update

error_handler $?  3


echo -e "${GREEN}Step 4: upgrade packages${NOCOLOR}"
echo -e "${YELLOW}apt-get upgrade${NOCOLOR}"

sudo apt-get upgrade

error_handler $?  4


echo -e "${GREEN}Step 5: upgrade distribution${NOCOLOR}"
echo -e "${YELLOW}apt-get dist-upgrade${NOCOLOR}"

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

error_handler $?  5


echo -e "${GREEN}Step 6: remove unused packages${NOCOLOR}"
echo -e "${YELLOW}apt-get --purge autoremove${NOCOLOR}"

sudo apt-get --purge autoremove

error_handler $?  6


echo -e "${GREEN}Step 7: clean up${NOCOLOR}"
echo -e "${YELLOW}apt-get autoclean${NOCOLOR}"

sudo apt-get autoclean

error_handler $?  7
```

Comment: "Simple" and "Upgrade" - two words that rarely go together without a negative somewhere nearby...

Comment: I know you've said you're not interested in logging, but your view on that will change the first time something fails and you have to try to figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Don't use non-portable terminal escape codes

The `tput` program exists for exactly this purpose:

```
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
nocolor=$(tput sgr0)
```

(I've downcased your variable names, to avoid surprising conflicts with environment variables)

## Inline the single use functions

`show_success` and `show_error_and_exit` are laudable, and do help readability, but they are only used once each, and may be clearer if written directly into `error_handler`.  Either way, their output really ought to go to the error stream: `>&2`.

## Reduce duplication

Look at this pattern:

```
echo -e "\n${GREEN}Step 1: configure packages${NOCOLOR}"
echo -e "${YELLOW}dpkg --configure -a${NOCOLOR}"

sudo dpkg --configure -a

error_handler $?  1
```

This structure is repeated throughout the program, but it can be refactored.  Let's write the variable parts using variables:

```
echo "${green}Step ${step}: ${description}${nocolor}"
echo "${yellow}${command}${nocolor}"

$command

error_handler $?  $step
```

There's three things we need: a step number, description, and the command to run.  The command needs to be an array; that's easy to arrange by passing it as *all the arguments after description*.  We can also inline the `error_handler`:

```
do_action()
{
    step=$1; shift
    description=$1; shift
    printf "${green}Step %s: %s\n" "$step" "$description"
    printf "${yellow}"
    printf '%q ' "$@"
    printf "${nocolor}\n"

    if "$@"
    then
        printf "${green}Step %s: SUCCESS${nocolor}\n" "$step"
    else
        err=$?
        printf "${red}Step %s: FAILED${nocolor}\n" "$step" >&2
        exit $err
    fi
}
```

This function is then used as:

```
i=0
do_action $((++i)) "configure packages" dpkg --configure -a
do_action $((++i)) "fix broken dependencies" apt-get install --fix-broken
do_action $((++i)) "update cache" apt-get update
do_action $((++i)) "upgrade packages" apt-get upgrade
do_action $((++i)) "upgrade distribution" apt-get dist-upgrade
do_action $((++i)) "remove unused packages" apt-get --purge autoremove
do_action $((++i)) "clean up" apt-get autoclean
```

You might choose to make the step number a global variable and increment it inside the function; I haven't done that, because global variables tend to proliferate and make the program hard to reason about.

## Don't sudo in a script

Many calls to `sudo` is a sign that the entire script needs superuser capabilities, so it's better if the user runs the script as root.  You could automate this (though I would personally just error out):

```
test $EUID = 0 || exec sudo $0 "$@"
```

---

## Full program

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e -u

red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
nocolor=$(tput sgr0)

do_action()
{
    step=$1; shift
    description=$1; shift
    printf "${green}Step %s: %s\n" "$step" "$description"
    printf "${yellow}"
    printf '%q ' "$@"
    printf "${nocolor}\n"

    if "$@"
    then
        printf "${green}Step %s: SUCCESS${nocolor}\n" "$step"
    else
        err=$?
        printf "${red}Step %s: FAILED${nocolor}\n" "$step" >&2
        exit $err
    fi
}

i=0
do_action $((++i)) "configure packages" dpkg --configure -a
do_action $((++i)) "fix broken dependencies" apt-get install --fix-broken
do_action $((++i)) "update cache" apt-get update
do_action $((++i)) "upgrade packages" apt-get upgrade
do_action $((++i)) "upgrade distribution" apt-get dist-upgrade
do_action $((++i)) "remove unused packages" apt-get --purge autoremove
do_action $((++i)) "clean up" apt-get autoclean
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is structured sort of inside out.

Also, as a minor stylistic remark, I'd [prefer `printf` over `echo -e`](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

run () {
    local task=$1
    local desc=$2
    shift 2

    #local rc

    # More portable would be to use tput instead of literal escape codes
    # Avoid uppercase for non-system variables
    local red="\033[1;31m"
    local green="\033[1;32m"
    local yellow="\033[1;33m"
    local nocolor="\033[0m"

    printf "%sStep %s: %s.%s\n" "$green" "$task" "$desc" "$nocolor"
    printf "%ss%s\n" "$yellow" "$*" "$nocolor"

    if sudo "$@"; then
        printf "%sSuccess.%s\n" "$green" "$nocolor"
    else
        # The fix to capture the failed command's exit code
        # was removed by the OP in an edit of the code
        # but I'm recording it here for posterity.
        #rc=$?
        #printf "%sFailure: %s%s\n" "$red" "$task" "$nocolor"
        #return $rc
        printf "%sFailure: %s%s\n" "$red" "$task" "$nocolor"
        return $task
    fi
}

while IFS=: read exit cmd doco; do
    run $exit "$doco" $cmd || exit
done <<____HERE
    1:dpkg --configure -a          :configure packages
    2:apt-get install --fix-broken :fix broken dependencies
    3:apt-get update               :update cache
    4:apt-get upgrade              :upgrade packages
    5:apt-get dist-upgrade         :upgrade distribution
    6:apt-get --purge autoremove   :remove unused packages
    7:apt-get autoclean            :clean up
____HERE
```

We use `read` with a custom [`IFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) to read the sequence numbers, commands, and command descriptions from a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document), which is basically a wrapper around the "real script".  There would probably be elegant ways to avoid wrapping it in a here document if you would forego the (IMHO slightly obnoxious) color output, perhaps by refactoring that to a separate script.

Documentation for using lowercase private variable names is available e.g. in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42847/are-there-naming-conventions-for-variables-in-shell-scripts

Comment: That looks very nice, but could you perhaps link some documentation and explain what you did to arrive at the refactored version?

Comment: You mean like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself?

Comment: Sure, but also like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document and http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html. If you prefer `printf`, explain *why*. If the script is structured inside out, *how so*. The `exit` doesn't pass through the status code, does it - not saying that's bad, just different from the original?

Comment: The answer does not really provide a review of the question.

Comment: @VlastimilBurian The parts you changed I had actually changed on purpose in order to improve the script, but if losing the failed command's exit code is specifically what you want, more power to you.  I'll add a couple of links to more documentation but I don't plan to work on other things.  The logic in my answer should hopefully reveal how I mean "inside out" if you compare it to the original.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for your effort. However, if I should say which one of the two answers I *like* more, it would not be yours. It is opinion-based, over time I came to realize I personally do not like HERE-documents. Plus, your answer does not really review the code, instead it only provides visitors with an alternative approach, therefore I de-accept your answer in favor for the other one. Cheers.

Comment: When you're using `printf`, it's best to avoid expanding variables inside the format string (unless you really intend for them to contain format codes).  Instead use `%s` to interpolate them as arguments - e.g. `printf '%sStep %s %s.%s\n" "$green" "$task" "$desc" "$nocolor"`.  We *can* get away with inlining `"$green` and `$nocolor`, since they are fully under our control, but `$desc` and `$task` come from outside the function, and deserve extra caution.

Comment: The change complicates the code slightly. And the values are in the here document so we have control over them, too. But I changed this because I basically agree. Thanks for the follow-up.